# Stellar support for Leger Nano X

Tags: ledger, ledger-nano

Is Stellar supported on Leger Nano X? If so, which firmware version is required?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see all supported currencies here: https://shop.ledger.com/pages/supported-crypto-assets.

> if so, what is the firmware version required?

Stellar is supported on Ledger devices for more than a year, so even the old firmware would suffice, but it's always recommended to use the latest firmware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.